# Plot highcharts using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

here Is my ajax request to get data and then call to function to pass data to graph.

```
function getGraphs(){

 $.ajax({

    type : "POST",
    async: true,
    url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Graphs/get_graphs",
    dataType: 'json',
    data :{hotel_name_realm:$("#hotel_names").val()},
    success : function(res){
     obj = JSON.parse(res);

     plot_graph(obj);
        // console.log(obj.upload);
      }
    });
}
```

Here is the Highchart graph plotting function. Ajax success function call to this function passing data. I have access this data object as ss.download and ss.upload graph was loaded but its not show the data.

function plot_graph(ss){

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        scrollablePlotArea: {
        minWidth: 600,
        scrollPositionX: 1
    }
  },

title: {
    text: 'Wind speed during two days',
    align: 'left'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: '13th & 14th of February, 2018 at two locations in Vik i Sogn, Norway',
    align: 'left'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
    }
  },    
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' m/s'
  },
  plotOptions: {  
    spline: {
      lineWidth: 4,
      states: {
        hover: {
          lineWidth: 5
        }
      },
      marker: {        
        enabled: false
      },    
              pointInterval: 60000, // one hour
              pointStart: Date.UTC(2019, 4, 9, 14, 35, 0)
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'Download',
            data: [
            ss.download
            ]

          }, {
            name: 'Upload',
            data: [
            ss.upload
            ]
          }],
          navigation: {
            menuItemStyle: {
              fontSize: '10px'
            }
          }
        });    
}
```

Comment: what is ss.download here, can you add some dummy data here?

Comment: @CodeReady I have updated the problem. ss is object that I passed from ajax success function

Comment: can you share the data which ss object consist.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ss,download` and `ss.upload` data look like this:

```
ss.download = [
  [Date.UTC(2019, 4, 9, 14, 35, 0), 20.9],
  [Date.UTC(2019, 4, 9, 15, 01, 0), 50.5],
  [Date.UTC(2019, 4, 9, 16, 55, 0), 80.4]
];
ss.upload = [
  [Date.UTC(2019, 4, 9, 14, 35, 0), 29.9],
  [Date.UTC(2019, 4, 9, 15, 01, 0), 71.5],
  [Date.UTC(2019, 4, 9, 16, 55, 0), 106.4]
];
```

Then I think you just need to remove the brackets around them:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Download',
    data: ss.download
    }, {
    name: 'Upload',
    data: ss.upload    
  }]
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/20gxfz9c/)